# Why YAML Schema (from JSON Schema) is returning $ref x in schema can not be resolved?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, swagger, jsonschema

I have this schema file in `./types/index.yaml`:

```
$schema: "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema"
name: Types in YAML
definitions:
  flow:
    type: object
    properties:
      slug:
        type: string
  flow_list:
    type: 'array'
    items:
      $ref: "#/definitions/flow"
```

And I have this "instance" YAML file, in `contents/en.yaml`:

```
# yaml-language-server: $schema=../types/index.yaml#definitions/flow_list

-
  slug: '123'
```

I would expect it to allow me to create a list of objects with the `slug` property on it (to get started), but instead I am getting something like this (with the `......` filled in with the full absolute OS path):

```
$ref 'definitions/flow_list' in 'file:///...../types/index.yaml' can not be resolved.
```

I am using the [RedHat VSCode YAML extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml). Any ideas on how to get it so I can write the array of "flows" here?

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if there is a bug in the VSCode plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting VSCode a few times seemed to fix it.